# How to fix "Extraneous argument label 'input:' in call" and sigabrt THREAD1 problem in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building a calendar app in Swift. It has a sigabrt THREAD1 problem and that strange mistake.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var wydarzenia = ["Wydarzenie1", "Wydarzenie2" ]

    weak var input: UITextField!

    weak var output: UILabel!
        print(wydarzenia)

        func show(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(wydarzenia)
        }

        func add(_ sender: UIButton) {
        wydarzenia.append (input: String).  !Extraneous argument label 'input:' in call!
        }
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Please fix your code's indentation to make it easier to read.

Comment: @GinoMempin There's a lot more wrong than the indentation. There are out-of-place and extra curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code is not complete.

It appears that you want to append an element to the `wydarzenia` array when you click one of the buttons, in that case you would need to write

```
wydarzenia.append("Something")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code here seems to be incomplete:

```
wydarzenia.append (input: String).
```

You defined `wydarzenia` as an [Array](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array) and an Array's [append](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126937-append) method does not have an `input` named parameter. That is what the error means, that you supplied an "extra" parameter to `append`.

> **append(_:)**
>     Adds a new element at the end of the array.
>
> `func append(_ newElement: Element)`

You can simply do:

```
wydarzenia.append(thingThatYouWantToAppend)
```

which, from your example, might be [the String value of the `UITextField`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619635-text)?:

```
wydarzenia.append(input.text)
```

For more info on how to use Arrays, check out the examples from the [Array](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array) documentation, like this one on adding elements to an array:

```
var students = ["Ben", "Ivy", "Jordell"]
students.append("Maxime")
```

---

In general, to debug your application, you can insert breakpoints then step through your code line-by-line, until you find out which line is causing the problem.

See the [Debugging Tools](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html) section from the Apple developer docs.